# ImportError: No module named *

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to create a web site on GAE.

I have an error importing module. Is something wrong in my code and structure?

ImportError: No module named appsite
INFO     2013-11-23 08:28:29,267 module.py:617] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

appname
    |-app.yaml
    |-index.yaml
    |-favicon.ico
　|- appsite/
　　　|-public.py

**app.yaml**

```
handlers:- url: .*
script: appsite.public.app  
libraries:  
- name: webapp2  
version: "2.5.2"
```

**public.py**

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add `__init__.py` file under appsite directory.

The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages;

For more info: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)