# How to handle 'ImportError: No module named profanity_check'

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, package

I am trying to make profanity_check run on a EC2 Linux instance.

The issue is that I get an `ImportError: No module named profanity_check` Error when I try to run **profanity.py** with `python34 profanity.py`.

Also, when try to run `python profanity.py` I get an `ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3` Error.

I assume this is because profanity_check only works with Python 3.

Furthermore I got an `DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life` warning when I installed profanity-check. However, I already have Python 3.4.9 installed on the system.

According to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160409/importerror-no-module-named) I already checked for the `__init__.py` file. It exists and looks stable.

The path to the `__init__.py` file is following:

`/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/profanity_check/init.py`

What could be the problem here?

**profanity.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python34

from profanity_check import predict, predict_prob

predict(['predict() takes an array and returns a 1 for each string if it is offensive, else 0.'])
# [0]
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .profanity_check import predict, predict_prob
__version__="1.0.2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've installed `profanity_check` for Python 2.7

```
/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/profanity_check/__init__.py
```

But your script is run using Python 3.4

```
#!/usr/bin/python34 <-- this here

from profanity_check import predict, predict_prob
```

Change your script to use python2.7 or install profanity_check for python3.7

Comment: Thanks a lot rdas! It seems like profanity_check only works with Python 3. That's why I got the 'ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3' Error when trying to compile with Python 2. After updating Python 3 and installing pip 3, I managed to make it work.